# confused about: (2.5) Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected

Tags: objective-c, ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I submit my App to App store, and after review it was rejected.
Reason from Apple was:

---

**2.5: Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected**

*We found that your app uses one or more non-public APIs, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines. The use of non-public APIs is not permissible because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change. 
We found the following non-public APIs in your app:

dateWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:

hourOfDay

minuteOfHour

secondOfMinute

setNavigationBar:

If you have defined methods in your source code with the same names as the above-mentioned APIs, we suggest altering your method names so that they no longer collide with Apple's private APIs to avoid your application being flagged in future submissions.

Additionally, one or more of the above-mentioned APIs may reside in a static library included with your application. If you do not have access to the library's source, you may be able to search the compiled binary using "strings" or "otool" command line tools. The "strings" tool can output a list of the methods that the library calls and "otool -ov" will output the Objective-C class structures and their defined methods. These techniques can help you narrow down where the problematic code resides.*

---

But, problem is that I did not declare or define any of methods with the names as the above-mentioned APIs. And I did not used any custom library. It is quite simple application (planer) and I used only:  UIKit, CoreData, AVFoundation, Foundation and EventKit.

I send message to Apple yesterday, but still no answer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Quickly grep your source code for instances of one of these (e.g. `secondOfMinute`). Do they turn up anywhere?

Comment: If you don't call any of Apple's code that uses private API, and you contacted them, wait fit a response.

Comment: Methods dateWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:, hourOfDay, minuteOfHour and secondOfMinute I used only once in my code:


int hour = [[[datePicker date] dateWithCalendarFormat:nil timeZone:nil] hourOfDay];

int min = [[[datePicker date] dateWithCalendarFormat:nil timeZone:nil] minuteOfHour];

int sec = [[[datePicker date] dateWithCalendarFormat:nil timeZone:nil] secondOfMinute];


where datePicker is object from UIDatePicker class:

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;


Same thing in the setNavigationBar method. I did not declare or define those methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said in the comments above you used

```
 [[[datePicker date] dateWithCalendarFormat:nil timeZone:nil] hourOfDay]
```

Now, `[datePicker date]` returns an `NSDate`, whose [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDate) shows there's no public methods named `dateWithCalendarFormat:timezone:` nor `hourOfDay` etc.

So, you can't just use them.

As for `setNavigationBar:`, the property  `navigationBar` of `UINavigationController` is a readonly property, as the documentation says. Therefore you can't set it.

When you compile your app, the compiler should have issued lots of warning about it, saying that the selector was not found, etc. You should always regard those warnings as errors, and eliminate them. This way you can avoid rejection after submission.

Comment: Yes yes, I saw that just few minutes before, and I changed that.

But what about setNavigationBar method???

Comment: dateWithCalendarFormat:timezone: is not any more recommended...

but what is problem with setNavigationBar:

UINavigationBar *bar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
bar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[opla setNavigationBar:bar];
[opla.navigationBar setTintColor:self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor];
[opla.navigationBar setBarStyle:self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle];

Comment: oh no, I just saw that navigationBar is set as readonly
my bad

thank you for your help

Comment: Let me say here again: there should've been tons of warnings in the build log. You should really carefully look at them. Happy hacking!

Comment: Is it really necessary to avoid all warnings. Sometimes they are just wrong, or they are stupid, like: local declaration hides instance variable...

Comment: Yes it's necessary. For example, that warning is not stupid, if you think of yourself reading that portion of the code half a year from now. Are you sure that you'll quickly be able to see if the variable in the method refers to a local variable or instance variable at a first glance, when you look at the code in the future? Removing all the warnings is a small price to pay if you want to maintain the code in the long term.

Comment: Yes. Every non-public API calls are warned as "matching selector not found."